# One to Many Search Query

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-many

I have a MySQL table where I am keeping a one to many relationship. The table is to store partner lists for a foosball stats program.  A player can have 0, 1, or 2 partners.

For example:

```
___________________________________
| Table index | Partners | Players |
|      1      |     1    |  John   | - Singles, no partners
|      2      |     2    |  John   | - Doubles, John and Bob
|      3      |     2    |  Bob    | - Doubles, John and Bob
|      4      |     3    |  Dave   | - Roto doubles, Dave, Bob, John
|      5      |     3    |  Bob    | - Roto doubles, Dave, Bob, John
|      6      |     3    |  John   | - Roto doubles, Dave, Bob, John
|      7      |     4    |  Dave   | - Singles, no partners
____________________________________
```

I am writing the PHP script to add and retrieve the partners from the table and I am having trouble with my queries. I know the players and want to retrieve the partners field. There are three queries I need to perform:

- check for no partners - Singles;
- check for a specific partner - Doubles with "Dave";
- check for two specific partners - Doubles with "Bob and Dave";

If the entry exists I would like to retrieve it, if not then I'll add that entry to the table. One of the troubles I have is for example, player "John" has three entries, no partners, one partner, and two partners. How do I specify only pulling out entry 1 and not 2 or 6?

I've searched here and found a couple of examples that are close but not exactly what I need. This one [mySQL: Querying one-to-many -table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328126/mysql-querying-one-to-many-table) almost does what I need but not quite.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Why does the last row, four partners, mean "singles no partners"?

Comment: You are keeping only derived information - this will be difficult to maintain. Don't you also need to enter the information who is partnering with who? In that case, just maintain a table of partnerships and derive the numbers of partners per player with a query.

Comment: Sorry, the column title "partners" would be better named - "partnerID".  It is a index indicating the partner relationship, not the number of partner a given person has.  My original post could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your schema correctly your Partners field is actually a foreign key into an implicit grouping table (i.e. it would be better named TeamId and key into a table called Team where each row represents one partnership).

Let's define the complete schema so we can work properly (this is essentially the same as your table, but denormalized to make it clearer, also you can just use a PlayerId rather than the name which allows for different players with the same name). Your many-to-many connector table here is PlayerTeam.

[image]

We can get the TeamId's and the team sizes for a given player by running this query

```
SELECT TeamId, count(PlayerId) as TeamSize
FROM PlayerTeam
WHERE TeamId IN (SELECT TeamId FROM PlayerTeam WHERE PlayerId = *your-player-id*)
GROUP BY TeamId
```

And you can get a specific sized team by adding a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT TeamId, count(PlayerId) as TeamSize
FROM PlayerTeam
WHERE TeamId IN (SELECT TeamId FROM PlayerTeam WHERE PlayerId = *your-player-id*)
GROUP BY TeamId
HAVING TeamSize = 2
```

You can also avoid having to query once per Player by using this query:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.PlayerId, pt.TeamId, sz.TeamSize
FROM Player p JOIN PlayerTeam pt USING(PlayerId)
   JOIN (SELECT TeamId, count(PlayerId) as TeamSize
         FROM PlayerTeam GROUP BY TeamId) AS sz USING(TeamId)
```

But to use this last one effectively, you'll want to user the result to prepare a conveniently-indexed associative array (like `$team[UserId][TeamSize] => TeamId`) to make decisions.

Comment: Your schema is almost correct, I have separate tables for player names and use their index in the PlayerTeam table.  I don't think the TEAM table is relevant for these queries.  The queries are just what I am looking for.  One other one would be if I knew both or all three players info.  I would presume I would have to extend the WHERE option of the first and second query?

Comment: You're right, the Team table isn't used, I put it there because it helps with the many-to-many intuition. Yes, having another IN clause with a subquery would allow you to specify more than one team member:
`... WHERE TeamId IN (SELECT TeamId FROM PlayerTeam WHERE PlayerId = id1) AND TeamId IN (SELECT TeamId FROM PlayerTeam WHERE PlayerId = id2) ...`. Not sure about how performant it would be however, but you can solve that if it becomes an issue later.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I was able to get the queries to work perfectly.  Adding in the extra player ID check worked great.